# How to create a view for logged in user?

Tags: 7, views

In user account (`/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`) I have a field that references to an entity: company.

I have a node-type, **dossier**, with a field that references the same entity as in user account: company.

How can I make a view where the logged in user only sees the user's own *dossiers*?

I tried a lot of things but nothing works. Sometimes the view is empty, sometimes the logged in user sees all the dossiers of the website.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't do it through the AI. I struggled with it over a year ago and never got it right. It's easy with a small custom module though which I can quickly type up. How many companies can the user's field reference?

Comment: Only 1 company. It is the company where the user is working for.

Comment: I think my answer should take care of most of it.

Answer (score 1):

I added an extra reference field to dossiers which refers to an user. In the view: add relationship to the referenced field and make it mandatory. Now it works. The logged in user sees only his files.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a view to display dossiers when the company's NID is the contextual filter.

The below is for a module called "custom_views_args" and it's the custom_views_args.module file. You need to change the field name, view name and display name. It should work fine.

```
<?php

function custom_views_args_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args){ 

// Load User - This is done and held in memory on every page load so don't worry about performance.
    global $user;
    $user_company = user_load($user->uid);

// Get the Company's NID    
    $company_nid = 0; // Might stop errors
    if (!empty($user_company->field_COMPANY['und'][0]['value']) or isset($user_company->field_COMPANY['und'][0]['value'])) { 
    $company_nid = $user_company->field_COMPANY['und'][0]['value'];
}   

// Hook Views Pre View 
    if($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME' and $display_id == 'DISPLAY_NAME') {      
        $args[0] = $company_nid; 
    }   
}
```

Works for me.

By the way, this question title isn't relevant to the question really.